# Merge anonymous number of arrays within an array to get flat one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of syntax like... I want to merge all the `arrays` within this `array` to have a single `array`. And after 9 the `index` should be 10...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 249
                    [address] => P.O. Box 496, 5760 Ultrices. Rd.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 0926 326 7612
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 2827
                    [address] => 885 Duis Avenue
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 070 6855 4104
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 3228
                    [address] => 861-6767 Mauris St.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 055 2515 3214
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 3327
                    [address] => Ap #815-4752 Tellus. Rd.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 07624 189445
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 3567
                    [address] => 1115 Urna Ave
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => (011221) 81949
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 4259
                    [address] => P.O. Box 177, 8135 A Rd.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => (014143) 06426
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 4547
                    [address] => 759-2274 Purus Rd.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 076 4327 8034
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 4607
                    [address] => 2858 Enim St.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => (01567) 19032
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 4660
                    [address] => P.O. Box 131, 3992 Ipsum St.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 076 4310 5712
                )

            [9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 4677
                    [address] => 2813 A, Av.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 0845 46 49
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 4783
                    [address] => 691-3213 Sit Ave
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 0979 238 0433
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 4807
                    [address] => Ap #735-3269 Enim, St.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => (0151) 751 9000
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 4934
                    [address] => Ap #423-7150 At, Street
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 0800 547 6093
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 4944
                    [address] => 996-9184 Orci. St.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => (0119) 522 6839
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 4977
                    [address] => Ap #844-7634 Nunc Rd.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => (016977) 8346
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 4990
                    [address] => Ap #330-2369 Pede. St.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 0920 046 1514
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 4992
                    [address] => 344 Nulla Av.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 0865 632 3945
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 5021
                    [address] => 442-7789 Quisque Av.
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 0332 016 9759
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ref_id] => 5056
                    [address] => Ap #489-6542 Proin Avenue
                    [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                    [phone] => 0352 327 2963
                )

        )

)
```

I have tried `array_merge()` but what if there is variable number of arrays in my parent array... Through Google I come to `array_flatten()` method but it is not working [I don't know why]

Required output is

```
Array(
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ref_id] => 249
                [address] => P.O. Box 496, 5760 Ultrices. Rd.
                [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                [phone] => 0926 326 7612
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ref_id] => 2827
                [address] => 885 Duis Avenue
                [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                [phone] => 070 6855 4104
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ref_id] => 3228
                [address] => 861-6767 Mauris St.
                [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                [phone] => 055 2515 3214
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ref_id] => 3327
                [address] => Ap #815-4752 Tellus. Rd.
                [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                [phone] => 07624 189445
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ref_id] => 3567
                [address] => 1115 Urna Ave
                [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                [phone] => (011221) 81949
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ref_id] => 4259
                [address] => P.O. Box 177, 8135 A Rd.
                [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                [phone] => (014143) 06426
            )

        [6] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ref_id] => 4547
                [address] => 759-2274 Purus Rd.
                [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                [phone] => 076 4327 8034
            )

        [7] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ref_id] => 4607
                [address] => 2858 Enim St.
                [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                [phone] => (01567) 19032
            )

        [8] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ref_id] => 4660
                [address] => P.O. Box 131, 3992 Ipsum St.
                [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                [phone] => 076 4310 5712
            )

        [9] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ref_id] => 4677
                [address] => 2813 A, Av.
                [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                [phone] => 0845 46 49
            )
        [10] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ref_id] => 4783
                [address] => 691-3213 Sit Ave
                [email] => itconflux@gmail.com
                [phone] => 0979 238 0433
            )
        ......
```

Comment: @Hashem Qolami... Well my purpose to add CI as tag is that may be there is some helper/class of CI for my problem so I can do this in CI way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_merge()` will work, you just have to loop through the main array and merge the inner arrays.  Assuming your array is named `$array`:

```
$result = array();

foreach($array as $values) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $values);
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Well thanks. It is so simple... That should have appeared in my mind. I thinks I should take some rest and definitely a glass of Coke...